# Vuetify - Autocomplete dynamic array data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to catch user input into my `autocomplete` and, when there is no matching with any original data in my `:items`, the component is cleaning the input.

Here's my `autocomplete`:

```
                  <v-autocomplete
                    v-model="oS.serial"
                    :loading="loading.bS"
                    hide-no-data
                    :clearable="!oS.statusEdit"
                    auto-select-first
                    :items="listBS"
                    autocomplete="none"
                    :rules="[rules.required]"
                    required
                    item-text="serialNumber"
                    value="oS.serial"
                    :search-input.sync="input"
                    label="Serial"
                  ></v-autocomplete>
```

I also tried to use `:search-input.sync="input"` but `input` stands with valor `null`.
When i click tab or click-out of the autocomplete, the inputted value is cleaned.

Comment: You can make use of combobox [https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)

Comment: Works fine! I'll create a new component using the combobox as default template. Thanks @beingyogi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @beingyogi commented, v-combobox works fine to this case. The `v-model` didn't get lost and now i can properly manipulate `:items`.